# When the integral is equal to the series?

Tags: calculus

How to prove that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} x^{-x} dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-n} \,?
$$

I think there are general theorems like this. If a function $f(x)$ satisfies some condition then
$$
\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n).
$$
What conditions the function $f(x)$ must satisfy? As I see, it is the very interesting functional equation.

Comment: This is a very peculiar identity known as the Freshman's Dream

Comment: Nope, actually this is the [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream).

Comment: Yeah, my bad...

Comment: Close enough. ;-) To the OP: the proof of the first identity is similar to the proof presented on Wikipedia. This does not settle your second question though.

Comment: For your second question, you could consider looking closely at the [Euler-Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Maclaurin_formula) and see if this offers any insights (especially the requirements on f(x) to ensure sums and integrals remain finite as the sum becomes infinite)

Answer (score 1):

Given any function $f$ for which the two sides of your second identity are well-defined and real-valued, you can add an appropriate multiple of, say, $\exp(-x) \sin(\pi x)$ to $f(x)$ to make that identity true.
So there will be lots of very uninteresting solutions.